# comparing a string, and, a string with only numbers

Tags: php

I am new to php and have been trying with no success to get this comparison working:

I have a variable 'productCode' that might hold

- Case 1: initially a value of 'Choose'.
- Case 2: Later the variable can take a string (with only numbers in it) like 102,103

I need to know what is in the variable productCode? Is it still 'Choose' or '102' (like string with only numbers)

What comparison operator should I use?

Is it having the value 'Choose'?
It should be

- true if the productCode was set to 'Choose' and
- false if it was some other string (with only numbers in it like 102,103..)

I tried

```
if(strcmp($productCode,'Choose')){

}//tried double quotes also

if(($productCode=='Choose')){

}//tried double quotes also

if(($productCode==='Choose')){

}//tried double quotes also
```

I am stumbled at this..
'102' compared with 'Choose' is also passing the if statement...

Can someone please help me with a correct method of checking this mixed case..

**Edit 1:**
The related code (after incorporating the === 0 suggesion by Rizier123 :

```
 $productCode11=$_POST['productCode11'];
 $productCode12=$_POST['productCode12'];
 $productCode13=$_POST['productCode13'];

if(strcmp($productCode11,'Choose') === 0){
    //testing the values if they actually hold what I am expecting
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert(" '.$productCode11.' ");</script>';
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert(" '.$productCode12.' ");</script>';
        //testing if the 'if' check passes
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("same");</script>';
        $productCode11Error="Fill This";
        $incomplete=true;
    }

if(strcmp($productCode12,'Choose') === 0)){
        $productCode12Error="Fill This";
        $incomplete=true;
    }

if(strcmp($productCode13,'Choose') === 0){
        $productCode13Error="Fill This";
        $incomplete=true;
    }
```

**Edit 2**
I did some tests and these are the strange results I got:

```
$test = strcmp($productCode11, 'Choose');
$test2 = strcmp($productCode11, $productCode12);

if both are 'Choose' I get 1 and it is incremented by 1 for every submission (2,3,4,5...)
if both are numbers and same, I get 0
if LHS is number and RHS is 'Choose', I get -1
if LHS and RHS are 'Choose' I get 1,3,4..
if LHS is 'Choose' and RHS is number I get 1
if both are numbers, and LHS > RHS I get 1
if both are numbers and RHS > LHS I get -3
```

Comment: Your third example is the one I'd go with. http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php has information on comparisons in PHP.

Comment: https://eval.in/394835 - how you compare?

Answer (score 1):

Your first attempt just works as it should. But you have to know, that [`strcmp()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php) return 0, when the strings are equal, so just add a comparison, e.g.

```
if(strcmp($productCode, 'Choose') === 0) {
                                //^^^^^ See here

}
```

So with this it will evaluate as TRUE if `$productCode` is equal to `"Choose"`.

**Sidenote:**

- [`strcmp()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php) is case-sensitive, means: `aA != aa`
- [`strcasecmp()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php) is case-insensitive, means `aA == aa`

Comment: Tried this..it works when the variable had 'Choose'. But later when it is set to 102 or like that it is still passing the if clause..

Comment: @dna Then please add your **full** and **real** code + your expected behaviour of the code. This code should work fine as you want it to. (*//tried double quotes also* Also note, that quotes doesn't make any difference here)

Comment: @dna So where are we now with this question? Also did you saw the comment from Mark Baker: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31289223/comparing-a-string-and-a-string-with-only-numbers#comment50570707_31289282 ?!

Comment: ok..i was trying to post the code here..sorry..check the edit

Comment: @dna Please don't post code as comment! Edit your question

Comment: @dna And what is wrong with your edited code now? As I already said also add what the current output is and what you expected to get

Comment: Your suggestion is right. I tried this with empty php with assigned values instead of getting from POST, and it works with any combination.. Looks like there is some unknown thing happening with my code. I will get back after some more testing. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

After a long trial and error, I suspected that the variables returning from $POST are probably having some extra characters. To address this I tried using `trim()` function. Surprisingly everything started working 'AS EXPECTED'.

*(And I am sticking to the === 0 suggestion by Rizier123)*